# How to Edit Font Size List

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to see all numbers between 9 and 24. How can i edit this list?

[image: Font Size List]

Comment: I think this'll require a custom JavaScript dropdown with .css values of your own to replace the default font-size menu. Just FYI you can always write on the font-size box e.g. `10 px` to adjust the font-size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! By adding a style that begins with .ms-rteFontSize, SharePoint adds a font size to the font size dropdown. The following example adds two font sizes to the ribbon;

.ms-rteFontSize-RandysFontSize {
    font-size:14px;
}

.ms-rteFontSize-RandysFontSize2 {
    font-size:15px;
}